# Raspberry Pi Database Server

Tags: php, python, mysql

I would like to host a database on my raspberry pi to which I can access from any device. I would like to access the contents of the database using python.

What I've done so far:

1. I installed the necessary mysql packages, including apache 2.
2. I created my first database which I named test.
3. I wrote a simple php
       script that connects and displays all the contents of my simple
       database. The script is located on the raspberry pi at /var/www/html
       and is executed when I enter the following from my laptop
       (192.168.3.14/select.php)

Now my goal is to be able to connect to the database using python from my laptop. But I seem to have an error connecting to it, this is what I wrote to connect to it.

db = MySQLdb.connect("192.168.3.14","root","12345","test" )

Any help or direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

on the terminal of your raspi use the following command:
mysql -u -p -h --port

where you switch out your hostname with your ip address. since currently you can only connect via local host

Answer (score 0):

at first step is check you haven't firewall rules on raspberry or in your lattop

after you can try this command on mysql

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
```

and remember to apply new privileges

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

for more detail you can see 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html

is similar for mariadb ecc...

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are not able to connect to the database from outside of localhost is that the remote access for the root user is prohibited by default, i.e. you can only access the database with the root user from localhost. You can, however, change this by tweaking root's privileges. Please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14779244/3628578) to find out how the user privileges need to be change to make this work.